# How to return false from a PHP script from inside a class/function?

Tags: php

How can I make **the main PHP script** return `false` from inside a class or a function?

Why: this is because of the built-in webserver:

> If a PHP file is given on the command line when the web server is started it is treated as a "router" script. The script is run at the start of each HTTP request. **If this script returns FALSE, then the requested resource is returned as-is.**
>
> *from the documentation about the [PHP Built-in webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)*

In other words, you return `false` in your router script so that the built-in webserver can serve **static files**. Example from the documentation:

```
if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    return false;    // serve the requested resource as-is.
} else { 
    echo "<p>Welcome</p>";
}
```

The thing is that I'm trying to add that behavior to a web framework: I don't want to write that into `index.php`. I'd rather encapsulate that logic into a class (middleware) that will halt the script's execution if `php_sapi_name() == 'cli-server'` and a static asset is asked.

However, I don't know how I can make the whole PHP script return `false` from a class or a function, since obviously `return false` will return from the current method/function/file and not from the main file.

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior with `exit()` for example? I realize I don't even know what `return false` in the main file actually means (is that a specific exit code?).

Comment: @Terminus `return false` has a specific meaning for PHP's built-in server, see the documentation I quoted.

Answer (score 6):

You should have the router invoke the class method, and then, if the method returns false, you return false from your router file.

Of course it can turn into a headache. There are basically only two methods to achieve what you want to achieve.

There is a faster way though, you can abuse exceptions and create a specialized exception for the case:

`StaticFileException.php`

```
<?php
class StaticFileException extends Exception {}
```

`router.php`

```
<?php
try {
    $c = new Controller();
    return $c->handleRequest();
} catch (StaticFileException $e) {
    return false;
}
```

Once you have this kind of code in place, just `throw new StaticFileException` and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. I'm ideally looking for an equivalent of `return false` using `exit()` or something like that (if it's even possible…). If it's not possible, I'm afraid I'll indeed have to look into workarounds :/ But I'd rather keep the `index.php` as small/simple as possible.

Comment: I don't get how wrapping the whole router file into a big try-catch complicates it. By the way: the only way to jump-back from nested contexts is throwing an exception.

Comment: It complicates it for framework users. I'm writing a framework. I want users to not have to care about this detail (because *they* will have to write and understand the `index.php`). Also `die()`, `exit()`, etc are other ways to break nested contexts.

Comment: In that case have them (tell them) edit another file and use `index.php` only to handle that logic. `die` and `exit` don't really break nested context from a developer point of view, they just abruptly end the script. What you are really asking is: did the PHP devs have the webserver magically convert a special exit code to a static file resource? AFAIK the answer is no.

Comment: "did the PHP devs have the webserver magically convert a special exit code to a static file resource?" Exactly :)

Comment: This is the route I'd do as well, by throwing a custom exception you can then throw inside your own code a specific exception that says "Hey return false".

Answer (score 4):

If the method in your class handles static assets by using `exit` then the solution can be as simple as replacing `exit` with `return false` and having the caller of that method simply return the method in the global scope as well.

So if your class looks something like this...

```
class Router
{
    public function handleRequest($uri)
    {
        if (is_file($this->docRoot . $uri->path)) {
            exit; // static file found
        } else {
            // handle as normal route
        }
    }
}
```

Just replace `exit` there with `return false` ...

```
            return false; // static file found
```

Then if your `index.php` works something like this...

```
$router = new Router($docRoot);
$router->handleRequest($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Simply add a return infront of the `handleRequest` method like so....

```
return $router->handleRequest($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

This should have minimal side-effects on your framework design and as you can see requires very little code and refactoring because returning from the script's global scope only has a single side-effect in PHP (in that it returns the value to calling script *i.e. if you used `include`/`require` as an expression in an assignment*). In your case if `index.php` is the calling script then you have nothing to worry about here just by adding `return` infront of that method.

Of course, once you return the rest of the script will not continue so make sure it is the last statement in your index.php. You can even just assign the return value to a temporary value and return later if you needed for logic....

```
$router = new Router($docRoot);
if ($router->handleRequest($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    /* if you need to do anything else here ... */
} else {
    return false; // otherwise you can return false for static here
}
```

---

In general I would say that calling `exit` from inside of a function/method is almost *never* desirable. It makes your class harder to test and debug and really has no upside from the alternatives like throwing an exception, or just returning from the method, and letting the caller handle the failure scenarios **gracefully**.

Comment: That's a good idea. I just want to point out that today I don't use `exit()` at all. Static files are just not supported with the built-in server. The one thing that's making it hard to implement for me is that the framework is based on [middlewares](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stratigility/blob/master/doc/book/middleware.md). Since a middleware **must return a `ResponseInterface` object**, I can't return `false` (I'd like the "static files" feature to be implemented as a middleware to be properly encapsulated). Anyway, that's food for thoughts, thanks.

Comment: In which case the suggestion to the throw an exception and `return false` from the global scope with a `catch` block is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't possible to play with register_shutdown_function or with auto_append_file setting to deal with that? Not really nice but maybe that can do the job.

Comment: Ohh I like the way you think :P I'm afraid `register_shutdown_function` will mean I'm in a function, so returning false will end the function not the script :/ And for `auto_append_file` I'm afraid it's not possible to use that at runtime I couldn't get it to work, even in a dumb test file (additionally it would be soooo confusing for users, but why not).

Comment: You spoke about "exit" and also about a framework context with internal php webserver  it's why I made these purposes. I'm totaly agree with you: both of then aren't very nice.